# VueJS and Axios multiple base URLs for prod env

Tags: vue.js, axios

To configure my application in prod and dev env I currently use something like:

```
let baseURL;

if (!process.env.NODE_ENV || process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  baseURL = 'http://127.0.0.1/';
} else {
  baseURL = 'http://api.example.com';
}

export const HTTP = axios.create(
  {
    baseURL: baseURL,
    headers: {...}
  })
```

Then I query the API with

```
HTTP.get(...).then(...)
```

Now I need to connect to several endpoints with a different base URL.

I would need to do for example:

```
HTTP.userApi.get()
HTTP.productApi.get()
```

How can I configure a prod / dev environment using multiple endpoints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two options in terms of `axios`:

1. Create [custom instance](https://github.com/axios/axios#custom-instance-defaults) for custom requests:

```js
// Create an instance using the config defaults provided by the library
// At this point the timeout config value is `0` as is the default for the library
const instance = axios.create();

// set a default baseURL for this particular instance
instance.defaults.baseURL= 'http://new-root.com';
```

2. Use custom `baseURL` per request using the [request config](https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config):

```js
axios.get('my/url', { baseURL: 'http://new-root.com' })
```

Speaking of your case, I would create an `axios` instance for each "endpoint" - `HTTP.userApi` would be instance and `HTTP.productApi` would be another one. They can always share common stuff if you'd like to ;)

Good luck!

Comment: I accepted the answer but how do I create an instance HTTP.xxxApi  with export const HTTP = axios.create() ?

Comment: Use the full sample from version 1, and just export `instance`